# OCR of playing cards in a video stream

Tags: image, image-processing, ocr, video-capture

I investigating if there is a not to complicated project to have a camera mounted above a bridge table and identify played cards from the feed. A lot of bridge tournaments are broadcasted on-line but it demands a person to sit with a laptop and click ever card being played and is a tedious job :)

There are 4 players and my thought was to have a marked area for card to be played in before registered.

[image: Bridge Playing]

A few things I'm thinking of.

By using a marked for played card OCR has only have to be made in few occasions but can I reach a 100% success rate?  Will I need some uber machine to handle the OCR calculations and is there fast enough routines for what I want done?

Would be nice to hear your input, suggestions and if you have any experience and ideas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use an [**Image Correlation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_image_correlation). It's fast and precise enough.

Example in [**Mathematica**](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) identifying the suit (the same can be done for the value):

[image]

Comment: You can also do correlation of the entire card if you would like - given it is a tournament deck you could know what they are like ahead of time.  In addition placement of the camera to give a consistent view and minimize distortion would be helpful.  Perhaps looking down from above the table.

Answer (score -1):

Will something like this work?  https://vimeo.com/3563858

Comment: Nice video but how will that possible help me then?

Comment: Essentially, there are three problems you have to solve: calibration, segmentation, and classification.  <br/>  For calibration you'll store a background image and calculate & store the perspective transformation matrix (opencv).  <br/> For segmentation, you will need to do: 1. subtract current image from background that you stored during calibration, 2. locate corners with rank/suit, 3. normalize this corner using the perspective distortion matrix.  <br/>  1.  feed normalized corners to a "trained" neural network classifier.  <br/>  You'll find most of what you need from OpenCV.  good luck.